swiftui: NavigationStackHostingController containment skipped because source and destination were nil
Getting the below error when using the NavigationStack in SwiftUI for Apple Watch platform.
NavitigationView works well but it does not serve the purpose.
Not sure what wrong is happening.
Any help would be appreciated.
Xcode: 15.4
Target: Apple Watch OS 10.4
<NavigationHostingControllerCache>: MISS at depth 0 in free stack
[NavigationHostingControllerCache_UIKit] <_TtGC7SwiftUI32NavigationStackHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x1540f200> containment skipped because source and destination were `nil`
<NavigationHostingControllerCache>: HIT at depth 0 in free stack
<NavigationHostingControllerCache>: MISS at depth 1 in free stack
<NavigationHostingControllerCache>: MISS at depth 2 in free stack
[NavigationHostingControllerCache_UIKit] <_TtGC7SwiftUI32NavigationStackHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x1540f200>     containment skipped because sourceNavigationController     and destination were equal     Optional(<SwiftUI.UIKitNavigationController: 0x14c18200>)
[NavigationHostingControllerCache_UIKit] <_TtGC7SwiftUI32NavigationStackHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x15424400> containment skipped because sourceNavigationController or destination were nil
[NavigationHostingControllerCache_UIKit] <_TtGC7SwiftUI32NavigationStackHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x15432800> containment skipped because sourceNavigationController or destination were nil

Code:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct WearableBankingApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView1()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView1: View {
        
    @State var path = NavigationPath(["1", "2"])
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Go to int screen", value: "1")
                 
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { value in
                Text("This is a string screen with value: \(value)")
            }
        }
    }
}


Seems like the code below is probably more what you're going for?
struct ContentView1: View {
    
    var destinations = ["1", "2"]
    @State var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(destinations) { value in
                    NavigationLink("Go to int screen", value: value)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { value in
                Text("This is a string screen with value: \(value)")
            }
        }
    }
}


In your code there is a error: Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument type 'Range' caused by ForEach(destinations) { value in. Replace this line code to : ForEach(destinations, id: \.self) { value in
